# Add user role to generated plugin

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I used the generator by Jeremy Hixon to create an options page but this page is only accessible to the admin user. I would like to make this available to the editor.

I have looked to add_role but I am not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

```
 * Generated by the WordPress Option Page generator
 * at http://jeremyhixon.com/wp-tools/option-page/
 */

class Example {
    private $example_options;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'example_add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'example_page_init' ) );
    }

    public function example_add_plugin_page() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Example', // page_title
            'Example', // menu_title
            'manage_options', // capability
            'example', // menu_slug
            array( $this, 'example_create_admin_page' ), // function
            'dashicons-admin-generic', // icon_url
            2 // position
        );
    }

    public function example_create_admin_page() {
        $this->example_options = get_option( 'example_option_name' ); ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Example</h2>
            <p>some description</p>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                    settings_fields( 'example_option_group' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'example-admin' );
                    submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php }

    public function example_page_init() {
        register_setting(
            'example_option_group', // option_group
            'example_option_name', // option_name
            array( $this, 'example_sanitize' ) // sanitize_callback
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'example_setting_section', // id
            'Settings', // title
            array( $this, 'example_section_info' ), // callback
            'example-admin' // page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'text_label_0', // id
            'text-label', // title
            array( $this, 'text_label_0_callback' ), // callback
            'example-admin', // page
            'example_setting_section' // section
        );
    }

    public function example_sanitize($input) {
        $sanitary_values = array();
        if ( isset( $input['text_label_0'] ) ) {
            $sanitary_values['text_label_0'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['text_label_0'] );
        }

        return $sanitary_values;
    }

    public function example_section_info() {
        
    }

    public function text_label_0_callback() {
        printf(
            '<input class="regular-text" type="text" name="example_option_name[text_label_0]" id="text_label_0" value="%s">',
            isset( $this->example_options['text_label_0'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->example_options['text_label_0']) : ''
        );
    }

}
if ( is_admin() )
    $example = new Example();

/* 
 * Retrieve this value with:
 * $example_options = get_option( 'example_option_name' ); // Array of All Options
 * $text_label_0 = $example_options['text_label_0']; // text-label
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), you'll see the third argument is:

> The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.

In WordPress you don't require specific roles for permissions, you require a [capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/), and roles are collections of capabilities. Your menu page requires `manage_options`, which is only held by administrators by default. If you want to also allow access to Editors, then `edit_pages` is a capability only held by Administrators and Editors.

```
add_menu_page(
    'Example', // page_title
    'Example', // menu_title
    'edit_pages', // capability
    'example', // menu_slug
    array( $this, 'example_create_admin_page' ), // function
    'dashicons-admin-generic', // icon_url
    2 // position
);
```

Now the admin menu item will appears for any user with a role that has the `edit_pages` capability, which by default is just Administrators and Editors.

You will run into another issue though. Your admin page contains settings fields created with the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/). By default, *regardless of the capability used to add the admin menu item*, `manage_options` is required to submit settings forms.

To get around this, you need to use the [`option_page_capability_{$option_page}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/) filter. With this filter you can change the required capability to submit your settings page. You just need to replace `{$option_page}` with the value that you passed to `settings_fields()` (which is, very frustratingly, the option *group*, not the option *page*).

```
add_filter(
    'option_page_capability_example_option_group',
    function() {
        return 'edit_pages';
    }
);
```